# How to run code when a item on the tab bar is pressed?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, uitabbarcontroller

How to run code when a item on the tab bar is pressed?
I am using the Tab Bar template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the UITabBarControllerDelegate protocol and implement tabBarController:didSelectViewController: to run your code.

Answer (score 0):

Toolbar buttons are similar to standard buttons. Therefore, you can also set IBAction by control dragging from the Bar Buttons to your view controllers header file and write your own action code.